# Installation of gcc-4.7 on Fedora 16 still shows gcc-4.6

Tags: installation, fedora16, gcc4.7

I built and installed gcc-4.7 on Fedora 16 from source. But when i go to the installation directory (/opt/gcc-4.7.0/bin) and query for the version `g++ -v`, i get `gcc version 4.6.3 ...`. I did not use any suffix like `-4.7` during the configuration, so my installed binary is `g++`. Is there any other configuration required post installation?

Comment: `./g++ -v` for security reasons the `PATH` does not include the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the path?

> which gcc
>   /usr/bin/gcc

To change it to /opt/gcc... you can either set the PATH variable:

> export PATH=/opt/gcc-4.7.0/bin:$PATH

..or create an alias, or set the CC and CXX variable to point to you gcc and g++ and then any ./configure / cmake / jam / etc should get the gcc declared in CC/CXX.